# Removed several programs using "sudo apt-get purge wine\*"

Tags: apt

I have been using wine for a while now but it started showing some problems a few days ago so I used this command to remove it

```
sudo apt-get purge wine\*
```

Now my system has none of the in built programs such as the terminal or the software center. What can I do to get them back apart from re installing Ubuntu?

Comment: You should be a able to get a terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+T does this work.  I know its not a fix but the answer will let us know it the terminal has actually gone or if it's just a problem with the menus/dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swich to a TTY (ctrl+alt+f1) login with your username and password, and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

That should pull in all the default packages that had been removed.

Type `exit` when done, then press ctrl+alt+f7 to return to the desktop.